# How does Jira "resolved" field (or its alias name "resolutionDate") get set?

Tags: jira

I am new to Jira and I have just joined a new team that is using Jira. We have a problem with our Jira Service Desk project's workflow. It looks like some months ago when an issue was moved to Resolved status, the Jira workflow successfully set a "resolved" field (which also has an alias name "resolutionDate") which is needed for reporting. However some months ago this field stopped updating, now it is no longer being set. It is suspected an ex-team member may have broken it while modifying the workflow. Can you guide me in how to fix this?

I can see from [this fields reference page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracorecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-765593716.html) that resolution / resolutiondate is a standard field.

Is there anywhere I can find more documentation for the field? Or how Jira workflows set their standard fields?
Should I be able to see the field being set in the out-of-the-box service desk workflow somewhere? i.e. where do I need to check?

Comment: I think you should look on the triggers of that transition. Maybe compare it with the default workflow that comes with a new service desk project

Answer (score 1):

You need to have admin access. Go to the admin section for the project in question and find the workflow on the left navigation bar.

You may have different workflows for different issue types. Nevertheless, the workflows should have a mapping of the arbitrary states (to do, parked, in progress, testing, etc) two 3 standard jira states: To Do, In Progress, Done.

AFAIK, moving any issue to a done state sets the resolution.

To edit the resolution fields, go to Resolution in the left pane. This article come might in handy:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/defining-resolution-field-values-861253253.html